TextView with ellipsize end and drawableEnd
i have text view which should be ellipsized at the end and can have drawable at the end. The problem i faced is that its inside ConstraintLayout and ellipsize to work i make android:layout_width="0dp" but after this my drawable is at the right of screen, but i want it to be right after text, how can i achieve this?
here is text view
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_goneMarginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/other_tv"
            tools:drawableEnd="@drawable/icon"
            tools:text="TestTestTestTestTest" />

here is how it looks:
enter image description here
i tried deleting drawable padding but it doesnt help

ellipse only works if you have fix width and fix lines in TextView. You have to set the width and line count of TextView

ellipse works here, its not the problem, problem in drawable displaying at the right of screen and not right after text

Same thing Setting Views's width to android:layout_width="0dp" makes it cover the whole width .. You need to fix the max width of your view.. See this for an example.

You have used  0dp which means your textView will take whatever space is there. so If you can do is set the width to wrap content and set drawableEnd or place an ImageView right next to it.

The solution would be to implement what @Laser said in the previous comment.
